# Detect when HDMI cable is plugged in Desktop Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, hdmi

I need to detect when an HDMI cable has been plugged or unplugged. Getting a notification would be best, but polling would also do. I am using Qt (and Qt Creator as IDE). I don't need this to be cross platform, I can use OS-specific system calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just from the top of my head: you can write a `udev` rule which sends a message via `dbus` to your application.